# Dataweave 2.0 reduce function to reduce the array of json Mule

Tags: mule, dataweave, mule4

My Input Json Looks like below :-

```
[{
        "eId": "123",
        "eType": "NZ",
        "value": [{
                "tId": "444"
            }, {
                "tId": "555"
            }
        ]
    }, {
        "eId": "456",
        "eType": "AU",
        "value": [{
                "tId": "666"
            }
        ]
    }
]
```

Expected Output Json to be like :

```
 [{
        "eId": "123",
        "eType": "NZ",
        "tId": "444"
    }, {
        "eId": "123",
        "eType": "NZ",
        "tId": "555"
    }, {
        "eId": "456",
        "eType": "AU",
        "tId": "666"
    }
]
```

I tried Transform using the reduce function like below. I am not getting expected response

```
%dw 2.0
output application/json
---
payload reduce ((val, acc = []) -> 
acc + {
    "id" : val.eId, "type": val.eType, "Tid": val.value map $.tId
})
```

Could someone please correct me where I am doing it wrong

Comment: The example output is not useful. You need to give an example of what should happen for more than one element in the main array, and add type to the example output.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'll make an educated guess, because the example expected output is incomplete, that the expected output should look like:

```
[
  {
    "eId": "123",
    "type": "Co",
    "tId": "444"
  },
  {
    "eId": "123",
    "type": "Co",
    "tId": "555"
  }
]
```

Script:

```
%dw 2.0
output application/json
fun mapItem(i) = i.value map { eId: i.eId, "type": i.eType, tId: $.tId }
---
payload flatMap mapItem($)
```

Feel free to *edit the question* to add more details if needed.

Answer (score 1):

You can try using the following dataweave expression:

```
%dw 2.0
output application/json
---
flatten(payload map (it1, ix1) -> 
    it1.value map (it2, ix2) -> {
        eId: it1.eId,
        eType: it1.eType,
        tId: it2.tId
    })
```

Comment: This is creating array of array as response.( not generating expected response)

Comment: You are right. Sorry for that. I've just updated the DW expression to solve it.

Answer (score 0):

Try with this.

```
%dw 2.0
output application/json
var inp = payload
---
payload[0].value map {
    eId: inp[0].eId,
    Tid: $.tId
}
```

Comment: It does not work for all the request. if you have more than a object in the given array

Comment: That solution was purely based on the ask.. Here is the updated one

Answer (score 0):

Updated solution

```
%dw 2.0
output application/json

---
payload flatMap ((item, index) ->  { 
     a: item.value map {
         eId:item.eId,
         eType: item.eType,
         tId: $.tId
     }}.a)
```